# Python XOR Encryption program sometimes doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, cryptography, xor

I am trying to make a simple xor encryption program in python and what I have now is working almost fine, only sometimes it doesn't and I just can't figure out why. For example, if I input 'hello' and the key '1234' it will encrypt it to YW_X^ and if I then decrypt this with the same key it will print 'hello'. But if I change the key to 'qwer' the encrypted message is something like '^Y^R     ^^^^' and if I try to decrypt it, 'heERQWERoi' comes out. 
This is the code:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip


choice = int(raw_input('Press 1 to encrypt, 2 to decrypt.  '))
if choice == 1:
    message = raw_input('Enter message to be encrypted:   ')
    privatekey = raw_input('Enter a private key:   ')
    encrypted_message = ''.join(chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in izip(message, cycle(privatekey)))
    print 'Encrypted message:' 
    print encrypted_message
elif choice == 2:
    todecrypt = raw_input('Enter a message to be decrypted:   ')
    otherprivatekey = raw_input('Enter the private key:  ')
    decrypted_message = ''.join(chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in izip(todecrypt, cycle(otherprivatekey)))
    print 'Decrypted message:'
    print decrypted_message
```

I have no idea what is wrong with it so I would really appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why xor encryption?

Comment: just out of interest, i'm not really gonna use it for anything

Answer (score 0):

It's probably working fine, but you are getting characters which you may not be able to re-input into your terminal directly as they don't correspond to the ordinarily inputtable ASCII characters. In particular, with the key `qwer`, the values of `ord` become `[25, 18, 9, 30, 30]`, which you may have a hard time inputting (cf. [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

The similar problem will not occur if you use `1234` as a key as in that case the values are `[89, 87, 95, 88, 94]` which correspond to "normal" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is printing non-printing characters, which sometimes can't be copy/pasted. You could encode the ciphertext into a format that uses only the characters `abcdef0123456789`, which lets you display it without issue:

```
print encrypted_message.encode('hex')
```

You can then decode it when the user types it in once more:

```
todecrypt = raw_input('Enter a message to be decrypted:   ').decode('hex')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured it had something to do with that but didn't know there actually was a solution to it.